# Is C notably faster than C++

Tags: c++, c, performance

As far as I understand all scripting languages and core scientific programs are usually written in C; this renders the implementation messy yet in a way straight to the point.

I understand these people would like to max their performance but is there a real difference between using C strings and C structures to using C++ classes; C++ seems to work the same way, apart from virtual functions, it stores a class function once and every instance of that class calls that one function.

What makes C faster and is it a notable difference in a project such as python or sqlite who have to be the fastest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618957/is-c-faster-than-c

Comment: "Well written code in any language is always better than poorly written code in any other language."

Comment: Many of these projects started before C++ was widely accepted and in a suitable state. Inertia keeps people using C.

Comment: @David - Intertia and the desire for a standard ABI for interacting with code written in other languages.

Comment: @RedGruttyBrick you should ask question which spark thought and interest; it answerable, it just takes longer to write

Comment: @Chris `extern "C"` gives you a standard ABI

Comment: @Will - No. "Is a language faster than another language" is unanswerable. Languages aren't fast, only their implementations. "Is X implementation of a language faster than Y implementation of another?" is answerable by profiling, but what do you profile? Language implemtations can be fast or slow in a variety of areas and testing all of them is undoubtedly impossible. A better question would be "Why do language designers choose X language instead of Y language?" That has a clear answer (the rationales given by different language designers) and is more likely to be helpful.

Comment: @David - For language design you'll need to have almost half of your code `extern "C"` for people to be able to hook into your language correctly.

Comment: The same code in C and C++ should *usually* run at exactly the same speed, the exception being code that has different semantics due to different aliasing rules, etc. The difference is between C idioms and C++ idioms. If you write code with best-practices C idioms in C or C++, it will be usually be much lighter and faster (and have fewer failure cases to handle) than similar functionality written with best-practices C++ idioms (regardless of whether you write it in C or C++), but it will probably take you a lot more work to write.

Comment: @Chris I'm not arguing that, you can compile languages such as javascript which was otherwise deemed slow. Although dynamic languages are inheritantly slower as they need to store the data in arrays and keep lots of meta data; you wouldn't publish C++ binarys with debug symbols because that's basically what you're doing with dynamic languages

Comment: C is notably faster to learn in its entirety than C++ ;)

Comment: @Gracchus We're talking about two different things here. Accomplishing common tasks is a lot easier in C++ thanks to standard containers and RAII and whatnot. I'm just saying that the language itself is so much bigger than C. If your goal is to learn C++ in its entirety to a point where you can take arbitrary C++ programs written by somebody else and understand them, it takes several years (about 10 according to many) of learning C++. On the other hand, learning all the intricacies of C maybe takes a couple of weeks or months tops, because there simply isn't that much language complexity in C.

Comment: According to this [old thread](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?103563-Is-C-more-powerful-than-Java) C++ "takes a performence hit due to the use of polymorphism" therefore C is faster.

Comment: @Celeritas: What you quote is not generally true.  On the other hand, it almost certainly is in some circumstances.  Runtime polymorphism isn't free in C either.  Throwing quotes around without understanding is dangerous.

Comment: @BenVoigt it was more of a question than an argument

Comment: According to "[The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/c.html)," C is overall faster than C++ for many tasks.

Comment: This day and age, and with C++'s advances in compiler quality,  compile-time execution, and some other language features - the opposite is the case. C++ will typically outperform C code - if you orient your coding towards performance. Specifically, the "best practices" mentioned in @R's comment from 2011 are now different generally than what they used to be ([and also formalized](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)); and doubly different when performance is key.

Comment: Let's recall Eigen, where library code is doing compile-time problem-specific optimization. C has no way to express that, and thus linear algebra code written in pure C requires lots of special-cased functions, and in general may not reach performance of C++, because in C++ the expression templates are interpreted at compile time and are used to select efficient primitive operations that implement the expression. FORTRAN doesn't magically solve that problem either. In C you need to write a code generator to take the usual matrix/vector algebra and turn it into fast code. Libraries alone can't.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

C++ is often used for scientific programs. The popularity of C may be waning in that domain. Fortran remains popular as a "low-level" language.

In C++, "you only pay for what you use." So there is nothing that would make it any slower than C. In particular for scientific programs, expression templates make it possible to perform some custom optimization using the template engine to process program semantics.

The reason C is preferred for projects such as Python is that it tends to be less confusing to read, so a large codebase will be more accessible to a larger pool of contributors.

SQLite has a requirement for small executable code size, where C does have a slight edge. Judicious use of C++ still allows use in embedded applications, but it is less popular due to fear that unwanted language features will creep in.

Comment: Do note that C++ does name mangling, where C does not, this makes it easier for other languages to interface with C directly.  (swig actually builds a C interface to C++ code for you prior to creating the python wrapper to the C++ library.)

Comment: @SamP C++ has a feature to disable name mangling, `extern "C"`. Swig happens to use C as a lingua franca, but you could implement that wrapper within the C-compatible subset of C++ and never invoke a C compiler.

Comment: "SQLite has a requirement for small executable code size, where C does have a slight edge." I don't think that SQLite written in idiomatic C++ would be any larger binary-wise or slower than the C implementation. It would certainly be lot less C++ code, and it could offer optional LINQ and compile-time query pre-optimization and compilation. C would require a code generator for that, and thus with SQLITE you can't pre-compile queries. A C++ SQLITE would let you iterate records with range-for without any intervening VM code, and it'd make the C SQLITE seem snail-paced in comparison. Too bad...

Comment: In fact, a typical size-conscious embedded SQLITE application has a fixed query set, and the database is memory-mapped from flash, with fixed schema, and the SQL interpreter and VM are dead weight, as is a lot of other code. I've done some experiments with writing queries using "raw" C, using low-level page access in SQLITE, and for my particular application I could discard 85% of SQLITE code, more-or-less. So, if anything, SQLITE loses out big time by not leveraging C++, but it's targeted towards platforms where no C++ is available, and they didn't implement a C code generator for queries.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica 1. C++ binaries have exception handling tables, which add a margin even when they're empty. 2. SQLite is bytecode-based. Compile-time query optimization in C++ would mean parsing and analysis in constexpr functions, which can't use pointers. That suggests architectural changes such that the product wouldn't be SQLite any more. 3. Isn't there a way to save the bytecode and strip away the text and parser out of the application & library binaries? 4. A parser-free or "headless" SQLite could interface with a C++ header-only bytecode generator/optimizer.

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't have the `restrict` keyword which can lead to some performance improvements in scientific calculations (although I'm not sure how significant this impact would be).

Answer (score 39):

I don't think that the reason is so much related to performance as it is to interoperability. The C++ language is more complex than the C language, but from a performance point of view there shouldn't be a notable difference in either way. Some C++ constructs are faster than the C equivalent (`std::sort` is faster than `qsort`) and there are probably good examples of the other way around.

*EDIT:* On the interoperability side...

Basically, the C++ standard does not define some of the things that might be needed for easy interoperability between binaries created with different compilers/versions. The most notable issue here would be the naming convention for the symbols in the binary. In C, the language defines a single mapping from each symbol in code to the binary symbol name. A function called `my_function` will create a symbol in the binary called `my_function`. On the other hand, and due to features like function overloading, the names of C++ functions have to be *mangled* (translated into different function symbols in the binary, encoding the types of the arguments and return types), and the standard does not define how the mangling is performed. That in turn means that the same function in C++ can be compiled to different symbols depending on the compiler (unless `extern "C"` is used to force C interoperability for those functions in C++).

At the end of the day, the interface between the scripting language and the native code would have to be a C interface anyway, even if the details of how it is implemented internally could be C/C++/any other native language.

(I am intentionally not wanting to enter into a flame war of language prefences, C++ is really powerful, but it is also a bit scary as it is a much more complex language than C, and some things that *look* simple might have an impact on performance)

Comment: I think one may confidently say that modern, idiomatic C++ requires an intelligent compiler in order to take full advantage of inlining, RVO, constant folding etc. With that, it's entirely possible that heavy-weight C++ constructions aren't noticeable at all at the machine level, but a good compiler is far more important for C++ than for C.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Most *modern* C++ compilers (where modern means last couple of years) are really good at identifying idiomatic C++ constructs and optimizing. The `std::sort` is one such example: the `std::less` functor used by default is not less efficient than the equivalent C function, but all compilers I know will inline it (being a template it is available for inlining) and remove all of the function calls to the `compare` functor.

Comment: Funnily, Electronic Arts's [EASTL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) library is partially justified by the claim that they found GCC to be bad at inlining (and MSVC to be much better) and that thus the standard library would incur too many unoptimized function calls. In EASTL they use fewer indirections to combat this. Who knows how well that reasoning holds up nowadays.

Answer (score 21):

As Bjarne mentioned in [D&E] the effectiveness is one of the main goals of C++.
So C++ is slower only when programmer uses its "extra" functions like virtual functions you mentioned, rtt information etc

So I think it is more of psychological reasons - C is used as it doesn't allow "slow" C++ features.

Answer (score 13):

Languages are not inherently faster or slower, interpreters and compilers might be more or less efficient.

Besides that, higher level languages provide abstraction layers that usually have a runtime cost. If you are not using them, the compiler might be smart enough to strip them out, but that might not be possible if the semantics of the language do not allow to do it safely... And if you need them, implementing them by yourself in a lower level language will be probably slower than using the "slow" language.

Comment: Scripted languages are inheritantly slower then compiled ones, unless you write truly awful compiled code

Comment: @Will03uk - What keeps you from writing a compiler for a usually scripted language?

Comment: @Chris then it wouldn't be a scripted language; the implications of a scripted language is that It's interpreted or bytecode compiled. Once you compile it, isn't it a compiled language

Comment: this is not the whole truth: language semantic do matter because they determine the information available to the optimizer and which assumptions can be safely made without having to perform whole-program analysis; case in point: the `restrict` keyword in C or luajit - the latter doesn't blow every other vm for dynamic languages out of the water solely because Mike is a smart guy, but also because Lua's semantics are pretty clean (in comparison to eg JavaScript)

Comment: @Christoph What I am trying to say is that there is no silver bullet. If you need things like dynamic dispatch, virtual calls, hot loading of code, or duck typing, a language that might seem "slow" providing it out of the box is probably faster than a naive implementation in C.

Comment: @Will03uk Strictly speaking, a language is not a compiler nor an interpreter, but an abstract entity composed of a grammar, a description of the semantics and possibly a description of what the standard library provides. That cannot be fast or slow.

Comment: @fortran debatable, yes some languages can be for example compiled or ran in a VM in the case of java, but the features of the language limit the methods of implementation; dynamic languages must do a lot more at runtime then the staticly typed C++ with symbols and stack variables. Even if say ruby was compiled, it would need dynamic functions, variable declaration, anonymous objects etc.

Comment: I'm not aware of any language that would be faster than any other at reading from disk, nor on socket IPC, nor on waiting on user input from a user who has fallen asleep.   Most often, C is not notably faster than C++, not even Python, because the CPU is hardly being used.

Comment: @Will03uk sorry I took five years to reply! I think you didn't understand my point at all. If in the statically typed C++ you need to use the same features that say Java or Python offer, you will end up building a dynamic runtime on top of your standard static runtime, which is likely to be as slow (or more, since you will probably can't afford the time or have the expertise to implement all the optimizations) as the language you are trying to imitate. You could also go the other way around, which is implement native "static" calls in dynamic languages.

Comment: -1, as a language, as well as its runtime, ABI, semantic restrictions can limit what the compiler is able to do with your code. And so can the common idios and the standard library for that language.

Comment: If you look at various implementations of common lisp (e.g. clisp vs sbcl), you see, that there is a lot of wiggle room between "interpreting on a vm" and "native compilation". The only feature, I consider a show-stopper for dynamically compiled languages ("scripting languages" which have a builtin native compiler) is whole program optimization as an image is never really done. But even for C/C++, this is a rather new feature and they used to only optimize on object file level until recently.