# Is the statement "C++ is slower than C" referring to compilation or execution?

Tags: c++

I never feel that C++ is slower than C. Did the people who say it mean compiler time?

I think in many conditions C++ is more reasonable than C             for optimizing such as reference.

Comment: "I think in many conditions C++ is more reasonable than C to optimize." - that's what Bjarne said too. However, there are some situations (for example, polymorphism, whereby virtual functions are called), when a C++ program can run slower than its C equivalent. Also, compiling C++ is a more complex task, so it is potentially more computationally intensive than C compilation (in C++, we have *huuuuge* header files, templates, type inference and whatnot).

Comment: It's possible to write C++ that's arbitrarily slower than C (especially by using lots of ill-advised virtual functions and such). Well written C++ is usually as fast as C, and sometimes substantially faster. Unfortunately, this question is likely to lead to lots of opinions and debate with little in the way of real answers, so it's likely to be closed as not fitting SO's format.

Comment: Agree with H2CO3. I recently wrote a C++ class which performed a non-trivial task. I created an instance on that stack, called it with constant values. GCC essentially pre-caulculted the result and optimised away pretty much everything. But when it comes to comparing the speed of languages, it comes down to the semantics and "practice" of those languages. If you created 'new' heap objects in C++ where in C, you might chose not to, of course it might be slower. V-tables might be slower in C++, but if you wrote the equivalent code in C and simulated v-tables, the C wouldn't be any faster.

Comment: Idiomatic C++ in the right situation can be much faster than C depending on what and how it inlines code.  For instance, the idiomatic C++ qsort can be lots faster because the comparison function can be inlined via some sort of functor versus the comparison function getting called for each comparison in C std qsort.  These idioms along with templates can make your C++ code go faster at the cost of a bit of bloat in the object code.

Comment: You would have to ask the people who said it. If they were referring to runtime they were either seriously misinformed or comparing apples to oranges. You can't validly compare a virtual function call in C++ to a non-virtual one in C for example. Stroustrup set himself a goal of no more than 1% speed penalty executing identical code when compiled by C++ as against by C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SO: [Is C notably faster than C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955114/is-c-notably-faster-than-c)

> In C++, "you only pay for what you use." So there is nothing that would make it any slower than C. In particular for scientific programs, template expressions make it possible to perform some custom optimization using the template engine to process program semantics.
>
> The reason C is chosen for projects such as Python is that many people understand it (relatively) fully, so a large codebase will not confuse many of a large pool of contributors.

In almost all cases C is valid C++ (since C is nearly a subset of C++), so there's almost always a way to do things that's *at least* equally fast in C++ as in C. As mentioned later in the SO answer referenced above, however, C has an edge on C++ in terms of space efficiency.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't answering the question "why do people say that C++ is slower than C".  People do say this, and sometimes it is true... usually with an inexperiended development team, or a situation where some of the slower features of C++ are warranted for some reason...

Comment: I think the question has changed since I answered it. When I answered, it was "When and where C++ is slower than C?"

Comment: How about concept based polymorphic?

Answer (score 0):

The people who say this do not mean compile time.   They mean execution time, largely due to the possible performance impact of virtual functions.

Comment: I think concept and concept based polymorphic will be better than the polymorphic now we used.